# Влияние хэширования md5(sha1) на производительность сайта

Tags: md5, sha1

Будет ли тормозить сайт, если вся информация в базе будет зашифрована (md5(sha1(информация)), и будет расшифровываться на сайте?

Answer (score 0):

Тормозить не будет по одной простой причине - md5 и sha1 - это не шифрование, это хэширование. Его нельзя "расшифровать" в исходные данные.

Comment: Тоесть в любом случае скорость работы сайта не будет отличатся от сайта с обычной не зашифрованной информацией?

Comment: @Ersultan нет, суть ответа не в том - вы просто не сможете хранить всю информацию "зашифрованной в md5/sha1" - потому что вы не сможете ее "расшифровать" для отображения. Хэшировать можно только то, что не нужно "расшифровывать" - пароли, например. Проверка паролей точно тормозить не будет (если  вас она проходит реже, чем миллионы раз в секунду)

Comment: ааа теперь понял.А нельзя ли скрыть имена,счета и т.д в базе данных?Чтобы,например,если кто то украл данные,то он не смог бы видеть эти имена и счета а вместо них другой код и т.д?